# How to check if an html element is attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception

So I am using a loop in python with selenium to constantly check on the attributes of a list of html elements, however once in a while one of the elements gets deattached from the document and another one is added in its place. when I try to check the attribute of the deattached element, it throws the error "stale element reference". I have searched about it and have found "NoSuchElementException" from selenium that supposedly would help me avoid this problem, however I do not know who to implement it correctly. Any other solutions/help with "NoSuchElementException" would be awesome :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you want to wrap the code that throws an error in a try except statement. smthn like this

```
 try:
     #this will always run
     #some code - eg. check element attributes
 except NoSuchElementException:
     # this will be executed if NoSuchElementException error is raised by code in try block
     # here you can do whatever you need
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the help, I just noticed I was using NoSuchElementException when my case needed StaleElementReferenceException, thank you for the help :D